# Is calling someone who resides in the country of India an "Indian" considered a racist slur?

Tags: word-usage, offensive-language, demonyms

This morning as I'm sure we all have, I was called by "Microsoft Tech Support". I wasted a half hour of their time saying I couldn't log in before they hung up.

Later I had told my Dad, as he asked if anyone called while he was gone. I replied with "Yeah, an Indian scammer working for Microsoft".

He got very angry with me for calling the man "Indian". He went on about how native Americans were classified as Indians untill the start of "Aboriginal" and that I was being extremely racist calling the man Indian.

He told me to look up why I can't, and so I did but what I had found all said it was fine, and to compare it to calling someone who's origin resides in Canada "Canadian".

So, I had told my dad what I'd found and he said it's different in Canada, specifically in BC because Aboriginals were classified as Indians. And saying "indian" people are going to assume I was talking about Aboriginals even in a context where I clearly refer to someone who's origin resides in India as "Indian".

So, assuming he is right, what do I call someone who was born, raised and resides in India?

Comment: It's not in the US - by the way that scam you are referring to is very nasty. It's extremely similar to the Cryptolocker scam which ransoms you for money by ciphering all your data and forcing you to pay money to unlock decipher it (there is simply no way to get it back without a reformat). Never ever give out info, personal details, etc... to someone *who solicits you*. That's the key rule. If you call that's different. If they call. Don't do it.

Comment: You call them Indian because that is what they are. They are from India so they are Indian. I can't, for the life of me, understand your father's point and he is definitely wrong. The only reason I can think up for him getting angry is that he thought the man you called Indian was native American.

Comment: @Phil14 Ya that's kinda what I thought too.

Comment: What is the correct term according to your dad?

Comment: That the scam caller worked for Microsoft was likely a lie, though you report reporting it as truth. As for the caller's national origin, why bring it up at all? Why not just call this person "a person"?

Comment: As to Native Americans (as distinct from natives and inhabitants of Bharat), the term "Indian" is not commonly felt by them to be a slur or otherwise inappropriate: at the university where I teach, there is an Indian Studies program, an American Indian Resource Center, and a Council of Indian Students.  "Native American" has its own problems as a term, as seemingly applicable to anyone *born* within the U.S.A. When possible, the most preferred terminology (if, again, an ethnic signifier is warranted at all) refers to the specific tribe or nation, as Ojibwe/Chippewa/Anishinaabe.

Comment: @dangph According to my dad the correct term was "east indian' enev though India is closer to our west

Comment: @Phil14 I can't either,  I specifically said I was refering to someone who resides in india

Comment: @BrianDonovan - This is the heart of the matter, not the word Indian. Ashton is connecting being Indian with scamming. That's a sort of piling on: "He is trying cheat me, but no surprise considering his DNA." I grant that you recognized his accent as coming from the Indian subcontinent.

Comment: I've *never* heard of East Indian. (BrE might be something to do with that) Sounds like a case of taking political correctness too far - as long as you were being *respectful* I don't see any issue.

Comment: _ *people are going to assume I was talking about Aboriginals even in a context where I clearly refer to someone who's origin resides in India as "Indian". So, assuming he is right, what do I call someone who was born, raised and resides in India?* _ well, I am that *someone who was born, raised and resides in India* and what I should be called other than 'Indian' -- I am Indian only. I should also suppose a lot of Indians from India are now working/settled in Canada -- 2 of my cousins are university professors in Vancouver, BC. Indian here refers to country of origin if your context is clear.

Comment: To me, East Indian would mean either someone from the eastern side of India or someone from the East Indies, which are the countries southeast of India such as Malaysia and Indonesia.

Comment: The real problem here is that if there is a group of people who thinks that members of group X are inferior, then sooner or later, referring to someone as a member of group X is going to be perceived by someone as an insult, even if you yourself don't share this view. And then the world has to find a new name for group X that doesn't have this connotation, and the rest of us have to keep up and learn the new name. I don't think the word "Indian" falls into this category, but there may be people who think it does, so who knows.

Comment: As for scamming, it's unfortunately true that if in the course of two weeks I get five calls from people with Indian accents claiming falsely to be from Microsoft, then I'm going to start putting the phone down very quickly when I hear that accent: sadly, this is the way stereotyping starts. I know there are hundreds of millions of wonderful people in India, but the ones who phone me are, statistically, very likely to be scammers.

Answer (score 2):

In the US, those who are residents of the nation of India can be called "Indian".  Those whose ancestors lived in the Americas prior to Columbus are called "Native American".  It can be considered a slur to call a Native American "Indian", but not a slur to call those from the nation of India "Indian".  Americans who have ancestry from the Indian subcontinent may be called "Indian Americans".

Sources:

[Indians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_people)

> Indian people are the people of India, the second most populous nation
>   containing 17.50% of the world's population. "Indian" refers to
>   nationality, but not ethnicity or language.

[Indian Americans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Americans)

> Indian Americans or Indo-Americans are Americans whose ancestry
>   belongs to any of the many ethnic groups of the Republic of India.

[Native Americans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_Americans_in_the_United_States#Terminology_differences)

> Native Americans are more commonly known as Indians or American
>   Indians. The term Native American was introduced in the United States in
>   preference to the older term Indian to distinguish the indigenous
>   peoples of the Americas from the people of India, and to avoid
>   negative stereotypes associated with the term Indian. Some
>   academics believe that the term Indian should be considered
>   outdated or offensive.

Comment: Good answer. Got a reference?

Comment: Great answer if credible sources are listed.

Comment: All because Christopher Columbus couldn't safely admit to his backers (Ferdinand II of Aragon and Isabella I of Castile) that he didn't reach his intended target the Indian subcontinent.

Comment: I added sources as per comments.

Comment: I bet you were a real party pooper whenever the other kids tried to play Cowboys and Autochthonous Peoples of the Americas, now weren't you? :)

Comment: @tchrist do American kids play "Cowboys and Indians" any more? They definitely don't in Italy, and in the UK, as a school children's game, it was practically antiquated by the mid 80s.